# Can Windows updates/patches impact calculated results of engineering software?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I work at an engineering company that heavily relies on the accuracy of calculated mathematical results produced by software on Windows 7 (MATLAB, ANSYS, internally written Fortran codes).  Recently I was assigned to a group that is responsible for ensuring that software on Windows isn't negatively impacted by updates/patches to Windows.  I was told the idea behind doing these checks was that an update to the operating system could potentially change arithmetic results of the software we use.  Supposedly there were problems in the past with software on Unix/Linux being affected by kernel updates.

The first part of my question is, how likely is it (or is it even possible) that an update to Windows 7 through patches, service packs, newer .NET framework versions, etc., can alter the results of mathematical calculations performed by software?  Could any changes to calculated results be larger than just the typical round-off errors?  Ideally a set of test cases would be run by each piece of software, but that isn't really time or cost effective to do every single Windows patch.

The second part, are there any suggestions of how to easily check if an update to Windows has caused any changes that might impact the results of our software?  As mentioned, running a full suite of tests on every piece of software isn't very feasible and I think our current process could be greatly improved on.

I'd also be interested to know how other engineering companies, especially those in regulated industries like nuclear and space, handle this problem of ensuring Windows software produces expected results for engineering calculations.  Do they also worry that every update to Windows will start giving them different calculated values?  I'm really not sure where that line should be drawn between being responsible in checking our calculations and being overly paranoid.

Comment: The basics: Not only software but also hardware may have impact on calulatiopn results - e.g. https://www.google.se/?gfe_rd=cr&safe=off#safe=off&q=intel%20floating%20point%20bug - but all this depends on which runtimes are in use for the particular software you're using; i.e. matlab in your case. Now, I cannot advice further than this - but can imagine there might be some kind of certification available. Matlab is used for so many engineering tasks that I would be surprised if it hadn't been thoroughly scrutinized (=> certified?).

Comment: I spent a lot of time trying to figure out which section of Stack Exchange I should ask this question on.  I felt it was ultimately about software/hardware so I chose Super User.  Any suggestions on what section I should have used so I can try and get help with my question?

Answer (score 0):

The .NET JIT could be updated to optimize floating point arithmetic more aggressively.

If an OS update enables support of a newer instruction set such as AVX2 this might also change the way IL is jitted.

I would not consider JIT updates to be exceedingly rare. They probably won't slip one into a security update but I wouldn't be surprised to find one going from .NET 4.5.0 to 4.5.1.

In fact, the new RyuJIT is going to be on by default in the next .NET version.

Besides that integer an IEEE arithmetic instructions are executed without involvement of the OS. Their result is specified exactly (that includes floating point operations).